# Adobe Flex: memory leak when pushView an popView

Tags: apache-flex, memory, memory-leaks, air, adobe

I am having problems of memory leaks with an app I had build in Adobe Flex, using Flex Builder. After using it for 30-40 minutes it starts to go slower and slower.

The app shows images as a catalog, but when I push and pop the views my memory rise considerably.

My thoughts are that if I set all my objects to null and dispose all the bitmapdata that I use I could free enough memory to keep using the app with no problems, but it seems like the problem is not there.

I have 3 views in my app menuView.mxml,categoriesView.mxml and productsView.mxml.

My App starts up in my pc (not in tablet) with TotalMemory: 47Mb and Private Memory : 88 MB

After pushing and poping the views for 5 times I get TotalMemory: 61Mb and Private Memory : 101 MB

Imagine if I do this several times. The app begins to go very slow in my Ipad or my Samsung Galaxy Tab.

Why is this happening? I have no idea how to solve this.

Please help! Thanks a lot!!

I put some code below.

When I am in menuView I use the following code to push the view from menuView to categoriesView

```
protected function button3_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if((FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.getIdClienteServidorCompraActual( )!=null)&&  (FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.getIdClienteServidorCompraA ctual()>0))
            {
                navigator.pushView(categoriesView);
            }
}
```

When I am in categoriesView I use the following code to push the view from categoriesView to productsView. In this view I have 3 buttons for each category.

```
protected function buttonC1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
            //Categoria general con todos
            var ab:ArrayCollection =  getIdAmbienteServidor();
           cleanMemory();
            navigator.pushView(productsView, null);
}



private function cleanMemory():void
{
    result.splice(0);
    result = null;
    System.gc();
}
```

When I am in productsView I use the following code to pop(I USE PUSH INSTEAD OF POP DUE TO DIFFERENT OPTIONS I HAVE) the view from productsView to categoriesView .

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    cleanMemory();               
    navigator.pushView(menuView);        
}

private function cleanMemory():void
{
    if(image1 != null)
    {
        image1.source = "";
        if(image1.bitmapData != null)
        {
            image1.bitmapData.dispose();
        }
    }
    if(image2 != null)
    {
        image2.source = "";

        if(image2.bitmapData != null)
        {
            image2.bitmapData.dispose();
        }
    }

    if(result != null)
    {
        result.splice(0);
        result = null;
    }
    if(result1 != null)
    {
        result1.splice(0);
        result1 = null;
    }
    if(result2 != null)
    {
        result2.splice(0);
        result2 = null;
    }

    dbConnection = null;
    object1 = null;
    object2 = null;
    dataToSave = null;
    cGreyImageSmallAsset = null;
    cRedImageSmallAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cRedImageSmallAsset = null;
    cOrangeImageAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cOrangeImageAsset = null;
    cGreenImageAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cGreenImageAsset = null;
    cPinkImageAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cPinkImageAsset = null;
    cBlueImageAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cBlueImageAsset = null;
    cGreyImageAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cGreyImageAsset = null;
    cRedImageAsset.bitmapData.dispose();
    cRedImageAsset = null;
    cGreenImageSmall = null;
    cOrangeImageSmall = null;
    cPinkImageSmall = null;
    cBlueImageSmall = null;
    cGreyImageSmall = null;
    cRedImageSmall= null;
    cGreenImage = null;
    cPinkImage = null;
    cBlueImage= null;
    cGreyImage = null;
    cRedImage= null;
    cOrangeImage= null;
    System.gc();
}
```

I load the images with.

```
private function setImages():void
{               
    if(object1!=null)
    {                   
        panelLeft.visible = true;
        buttonLeftMore.visible = true;
        image1.source = "file://" + File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath + "/b"+object1.idArchivo+"_500.jpg";
        setObject1MainTexts();
     }
     else
     {
         image1.source = "";
         panelLeft.visible = false;
         buttonLeftMore.visible = false;
     }

     if(object2!=null)
     {   
         panelRight.visible = true;
         buttonRightMore.visible = true;
         image2.source = "file://" + File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath + "/b"+object2.idArchivo+"_500.jpg";
         setObject2MainTexts();
     }
     else
     {
         image2.source = "";
         panelRight.visible = false;
         buttonRightMore.visible = false;
     }
  }
```

When I am in categoriesView i use the following code to pop(I USE PUSH INSTEAD OF POP DUE TO DIFFERENT OPTIONS I HAVE) the view from categoriesView to menuView.

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    cleanMemory();
    navigator.pushView(menuPrincipalBelda);
}

private function cleanMemory():void
{
    result.splice(0);
    result = null;
    System.gc();
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should never have to manually run GC, and rarely ever should you have to run a "clean up" routine on a DisplayObject. Simply removing it from the display list and nulling any references to it should suffice. It sounds more like you are leaking a reference to your view somewhere, preventing it from getting cleaned up in the GC. Have you checked for leaks in the profiler yet?

Comment: We also have this problem when develop an mobile app using Flash Builder. Thanks for this thread, I'll try the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Flex Builder uses the Flash virtual machine and this frees the memory when considered necessary, even if you try to force him to clean the garbage collector will not do if you have free memory and does not consider it necessary.
Test the movie ***embedded*** in the images you need in the application, and not constantly loading. Since this may be letting some low-level relationship.

regards

Comment: Thank you for yor reply matilu.
Do you refer to the embedded images?, I use var likes this ones that i write down for getting images that I use in my view.

    Embed(source="../img/cgreen_small.png")]
    private var cGreenImageSmall:Class;
    [Embed(source="../img/corange_small.png")]
    private var cOrangeImageSmall:Class;
    private var cGreenImageSmallAsset:BitmapAsset;
    private var cOrangeImageSmallAsset:BitmapAsset;

Comment: What I'm saying is that maybe you best use embedded images (depends how much you have to load pictures, but among all of them, do not overcome the 300kb, go for it), since the constant load of files can be leaving relationships low memory.
Also check that you have a background with Styles, event listener on the images you upload. Nor is it good launch popUp.
Unable to see the detail App I can not give me an idea of what else can be.
I hope you can solve the problem.

regards

Comment: Matilu, thank you for your comments. I will try it out and let you know it it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I discover the problem: I was not removing the EventListener, now is working fine.

I leave you guys with some examples. If you do not remove them, then memory increases a lot! Be careful with this.

```
stage.addEventListener("keyUp", handleButtons, false, 1);
stage.removeEventListener("keyUp",handleButtons,false);
xeasy.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, AppWS_resultHandler);
xeasy.removeEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,AppWS_resultHandler, false);
```

Thanks to everybody!!

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with GC I found that it became of advantage to try several different ways! I used 3 in total over time, but just can only find one at the moment as this was the one noticeable better working in this App. so here it is and if needed I can send the other two as well must just look for them!

```
        private var gcCount:int;

        private function startGCCycle():void {

            gcCount = 0;
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doGC);
        }
        private function doGC(evt:Event):void {

            flash.system.System.gc();

            if(++gcCount > 1) {

                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doGC);
                setTimeout(lastGC, 40);
            }
        }
        private function lastGC():void{
            flash.system.System.gc();
        }
    ]]>
```

I just was looking at something else which you should try as well it worked for me very well!

FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.deleteReferenceOnParentDocument(this) I used these in a creationComplete in MXML where I had to open 45 Main Canvases one after another but each time with three PopUps = 180 which was easy to handle in the way I worked the GC in! regards aktell

Comment: Thank you aktell, I will take your comment if I have problems with the GC.

Comment: That is fine! yet I see that you do not use IF possible and suited the same code on your second EventListener ??? xeasy.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, AppWS_resultHandler); TO test ! xeasy.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT, AppWS_resultHandler, false, 1); as well as use ADD in one & REMOVE in another function. regards aktell